# Follow plugin not showing up for my profile

Tags: facebook, plugins

I'm trying to add the "Follow" plugin to my website.  There are several methods for this (as described on the Facebooks developer page), but none of them work for me.

They do work with the example user "zuck", but not with my profile.  When I was trying the XFBML approach, I thought I was doing something wrong, but even the Iframe version won't work for my profile.  I can't explain this.

Plugin with default user (zuck's) URL shows:
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fzuck&layout=standard&show_faces=true&colorscheme=light&font&width=450

Plugin with my profile (middelkoopjan) URL doesn't show:
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmiddelkoopjan&layout=standard&show_faces=true&colorscheme=light&font&width=450

I feel like I'm overlooking something elementary, but I'm at a loss here... any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow subscriptions in your Facebook profiles account settings. Click on the 'Subscribers' link on the menu on the left side of the screen, and check the box on "Allow subscribers". That should enable the follow plugin to work for your profile.

Comment: I knew I was overlooking something elementary.  D'oh.  Thanks. :-)